# create android queries from database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is there any way to to export database in android format? like if I create a database using "SQLite Browser" and want to export in android query format like the one given below? and it should also create the statements for insert queries as used in android using ContentValues.

```
    // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }
```

Comment: It will export the "CREATE TABLE" and the "INSERT INTO" **commands** (not queries).

Comment: isnt their any other software that can do the task i require?? @Tobor

Comment: I thought THIS was what you asked. What do you need more? UPDATE, DELETE commands and SELECT queries? It's too broad, since the commands and queries would be so many different types (AVERAGING, GROUPING, WHERE conditions, EXTRACTING DATE PARTS, ...)